# Programming: "written in" vs "written with"

Tags: prepositions

When a program is written in a certain language, then "in" is used. But I don't know what preposition to use with frameworks and libraries.

For example, I saw that some people say:

> It's written in Node.js

But Node.js isn't a language, it's a runtime environment, so I would say:

> It's written in JavaScript with/for Node.js

But if one doesn't want to mention a language explicitly, what preposition should be used?

Examples with frameworks:

> - A test written in/with Cypress
> - An app written in/with Express

Also, I wonder can "written" be omitted? For example:

> There are many tests in/with Cypress

Comment: As a programmer, I see/hear both, but I tend to use _with_ or _using_ when referring to APIs or frameworks, e.g.,"That program is written with .NET". If, for some reason, I want to avoid using forms of the verb _write_, I'll generally use a form of _use_: "Those tests are using node.js".

Answer (score 1):

When referring to **frameworks, libraries, or runtime environments**, the preposition "**with**" is more appropriate than "in". For example;

> A web app written with asp.net core

In this case, "with" is correct because ASP.NET Core is a framework, and the web app is developed with that framework. "with" is used to indicate that the mentioned framework or library is being *utilized*.

On the other hand, when referring to **programming languages**, "**in**" is more appropriate, because the app is written using that language. For example;

> A web app written in c#

In this case, "in" is more appropriate than "with", because C# is a programming language, and the web app is written *using* that language. To combine the two, you can say;

> A web app written with asp.net core in c#

You don't exactly use a framework or library itself. You utilize a framework or library. You make use of it. On the other hand, you directly use a programming language itself.